# knowledge distillation in a multistep model

Tags: compression

I have a teacher, student and an adapter NER model. The adaptor is a standalone BiLSTM model that takes discrete outputs from teacher/student model and generates some logits. Now I want to do knowledge distillation but instead of calculating the loss from comparing teacher and student output logits, i want the loss to be calculated from the teacher and student outputs generated after passing through the NER model. The problem is in `pyTorch`, once the discrete outputs (that are input to the NER model) is generated, somewhere the computation graph breaks and i cannot backpropagate the loss to the student model. When I do

```
ce_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(teacher_ner_logits, student_ner_logits)
ce_loss.backward()
```

the loss isn't propagated backwards to the student model. I want to know if this is logically possible to implement and if so how?